# MySQL MariaDB not returning Top Value when Group By

Tags: mariadb

I have problem, that MySQL MariaDB not returning Top Value by grouping, when performing:

```
SELECT tusername, tuserid, count(*) AS cnt 
FROM tw_tab 
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2023-02-27 09:49:47' AND '2023-02-28 09:49:47' 
      AND tuserprofile='com' 
GROUP BY tusername, tuserid
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

It seems the MariaDB has a bug and already tried:

`SET GLOBAL optimizer_switch='derived_merge=OFF';`

But this setting is not helping, anyone can Help with this, or shall I kick MariaDB and use another DB?

Comment: Mariadb is not mysql. It's a fork of mysql with increased number of incompatibilities. Please also include sample data, results returned by your query and expected results to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Use all non-aggregate columns in the GROUP BY. In your case `GROUP BY tusername, tuserid`

Comment: You seem to be misusing MariaDB / MySQL's [notorious nonstandard extension to GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html). Disable that extension with `SET sql_mode = CONCAT_WS(',',@@sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY')`, then try your query again. You'll need more terms in your GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Thanks for your replys, already added tuserid to 'GROUP BY tusername, tuserid', then SET sql_mode = CONCAT_WS(',',@@sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', but still missing Top 1

Comment: I have a couple of thausands Data, already exported as Json, but don't know how to add accurate here