# Loop through SQL with "foreach"

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, mariadb

**I want to get a list (top 5)**, with the most active authors (WordPress comments). That's what I try:

```
function top_authors() {
  global $wpdb;
  $comments_table = $wpdb->prefix.'comments';
  $results = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT
    COUNT(comment_author_email) AS comments_count, comment_author
    FROM $comments_table
    WHERE comment_approved = '1'
    LIMIT 5"
  );

  foreach($results as $result) {
    echo "<div>". $result->comment_author. " und " .$result->comments_count. "</div>";
  }
}
```

**My problem:** I just get the most active author (one author), not the **top 5** authors. What's my fail?

Comment: When you have a SQL problem, you can allow contributors to test their advice for your precise task if you create a sql fiddle demo link and post it in your question.  Providing sample input data and your exact desired output is how you create a [mcve].

Comment: Potentially related: [MySQL MariaDB not returning Top Value when Group By](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75591034/2943403)

Comment: Thx again @mickmackusa , that can be the problem, damn. I will take a look how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT comment_author, COUNT(*) AS comments_count
FROM $comments_table
WHERE comment_approved = '1'
GROUP BY comment_author
ORDER BY comments_count DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Please never post "try this" answers.  Every answer should include a plain English explanation.  Even if the technique is very simple, keep in mind the asker and future researchers who are looking for such a solution probably won't know how/when/why to use the technique.  This is your chance to educate and empower others.

Comment: Thx for your support too. Same problem here. I also changed "comment_author" to "user_id", to check if that's the problem, but nope. I get the right names and count for them, but they are all duplicated in the list. More comments per user, more duplications per user. Is the "foreach" the problem?

Comment: Its now working, I did a dump "echo output" fail. So big thx for your support! But you should undo your last change, its still "$comments_table".